# Expo Google auth fails on standalone android app

Tags: react-native, google-oauth, expo

I am trying to implement google oauth with expo.it works perfectly on Expo but when i compile to apk. Once I click on google-login it opens a pop-up then i select my email after that it opens back my login screen again which is wrong.
here is my code below

```
export async function signInWithGoogleAsync() {
  try {
    const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId: ' ',
      iosClientId: ' ',
      androidStandaloneAppClientId: ' ',
      iosStandaloneAppClientId: ' ',
      webClientId: ' ',
      scopes: ['profile', 'email']
    });

    if (result.type === 'success') {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    } else {
      alert('authentication failed')
    }
  } catch (e) {
   alert('authentication failed')

  }
}
```